# Nested UIScrollView not paging for Internal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to build a screen which has 2 UIScrollViews, 1 Main Scroll View which is used as a container and to scroll vertically (this is working fine).

Inside the Main Scroll View, is a second scroll view, which is used for display different images. This needs to be scrolled horizontally so it will page to other images which will also update content details displayed in the Main Scroll View.

When attempting to get these two features to work together, the paging functionality does not work, however if it is outside the main scroll view it will work but will not scroll with the rest of the content.

The Image Scroll View is being detected in the events as well, but doesn't show any ability to scroll.

Below are my 3 functions which are performing the work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set up the Image Scroll View
    ImageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, screenWidth, homeImage)];
        ImageScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        ImageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     [ImageScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
     [ImageScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
        ImageScrollView.delegate = self;

    // Set up the image array
        NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"staff1big.png", @"staff2big.png",    @"staff3big.png", nil];

    // Create each image subview
    for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++)
        {
                CGFloat xOrigin = i * ImageScrollView.frame.size.width;

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,  ImageScrollView.frame.size.width, ImageScrollView.frame.size.height)];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

            [ImageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }

    // Set the Content Size and Offset
        [ImageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(ImageScrollView.frame.size.width *       [imagesArray count], ImageScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [ImageScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(screenWidth*currentIndex, 0)];

        // Get the staff object
        dataSource = [DataSource dataSource];
        NSArray *staffArray = [dataSource getStaff];

    // Setup the Pager Control
        self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];

        NSInteger placement = (screenWidth/2)-50;

        self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(placement, homeImage-30, 100, 20);
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [staffArray count];
        self.pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex;

        [self setStaff:staffArray[currentIndex]];

    // Add the Main Scroll View
        MainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,      screenHeight)];
        MainScrollView.delegate = self;
        MainScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        MainScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    // Add each object to the correct scroll view
        [ImageScrollView addSubview:self.pageControl];
        [MainScrollView addSubview:ImageScrollView];
        [MainScrollView addSubview:lineView];

        [self setDisplayContent]; // note the MainScrollView is added to the self.view in this method   along with setting the content size to screenWidth and height is determine by the generated     content.
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = ImageScrollView.frame.size.width;
    float fractionalPage = ImageScrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    currentIndex = page;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    [self displayContent];
}

- (void)displayContent
{
    int i = currentIndex;

    if (i < 0)
    {
        i = 0;
    } else if (i > 2) {
        i = 2;
    }

    [self setStaff:allStaff[i]];

    // remove all from view
    for(UIView *subview in [MainScrollView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"staff1big.png", @"staff2big.png", @"staff3big.png", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++)
    {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * ImageScrollView.frame.size.width;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, ImageScrollView.frame.size.width, ImageScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

        [ImageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    [ImageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(ImageScrollView.frame.size.width * [imagesArray count], ImageScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [ImageScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(screenWidth*currentIndex, 0)];

    // Get the staff
    dataSource = [DataSource dataSource];
    NSArray *staffArray = [dataSource getStaff];

    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];

    NSInteger placement = (screenWidth/2) - 50;

    self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(placement, homeImage-30, 100, 20);
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [staffArray count];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex;

    [self setStaff:staffArray[currentIndex]];

    [ImageScrollView addSubview:self.pageControl];
    [MainScrollView addSubview:ImageScrollView];
    [MainScrollView addSubview:lineView];

    [self setDisplayContent];
}
```

I do need to refactor some of the code to make more efficient, but at this stage I am just trying to get the horizontal paging to scroll horizontally.
If anyone would possibly be able to help point me in the right direction as to how to fix this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a visual of the UI that I am trying to keep but have the image scroll horizontal.
[Staff Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7MY7.png)

Comment: You can try using a collectionView instead of the second scroll view for horizontal scrolling. If it suits your needs you should use a tableView instead of the verticalScrollView.

Basically:
CollectionView inside of a TableView or if for some other reason you wish to use scrollView for vertical scrolling. Just use collectionView for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Can a collectionView be used to update the content that is displayed within the current scrollView?

Comment: I don't think that a collection view will provide with the layout or functionality that I am after

Comment: It can but it might be a bit hackish. I can't tell you for sure as i have no idea what exact flow you are trying to create. CollectionViews are highly customizable by either creating custom FlowLayouts or simply sizing cells. If you are simply trying to create a a full screen width imageView that is scrollable and updates the content below it, I would consider using a collectionView and tableView as all the scrolling is handled by them only and adding new content becomes easy.